# Kotlin Coroutines StateFlow not emitting identical values consecutively—How to force collection or work around this behavior?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I'm encountering a situation where a `MutableStateFlow` in my Kotlin code isn't emitting the same value twice in a row, even when I explicitly call `emit()` with the same value. This is preventing my collectors from being notified as expected.

**Here's a minimal example**:

```
private val dragOffset = MutableStateFlow(Offset.Zero)
val offset = Offset(100F, 100F)
dragOffset.emit(offset)  // Collector prints this
dragOffset.emit(offset)  // Collector doesn't print this

dragOffset.collect { dragOff ->
    println(dragOff)
}
```

the question is Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for working with StateFlows when re-emitting identical values is necessary?

**I'd appreciate any insights or guidance from the community on how to best address this issue.**

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use `SharedFlow` instead? This behavior is intentional for state flows, because changing a state to exactly the same one is a no change, so no emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to collect the same value twice in a row with state flows, because they're design specifically to react to a change of state.

If your value does not represent an "absolute state". (Ex: the position of an element inside a window), then state flow might not be what your require.

However, its parent class: `SharedFlow` might be what you need. Like state flows, shared flows are *hot, infinite* data stream that broadcast emitted value to all their collectors.

Shared flow are more configurable than Stateflow, and can therefore be adapted to more cases.

For example, you can instruct a shared flow to replay the latest emitted value to consumers, and to drop previously cached value. That should emulate a single state accepting duplicates.

Let's look at an example:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking


fun CoroutineScope.prepareFlow(): SharedFlow<Int> {
    // Prepare the flow holding only a single value at any time.
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(1)
    launch {
        // For this particular example, wait for a subscriber before emitting any value.
        // We want to be sure the collector receives both emitted values.
        flow.subscriptionCount.filter { it > 0 }.first()
        // Emit the same value twice
        flow.emit(1)
        flow.emit(1)
    }
    return flow.asSharedFlow()
}

fun main() : Unit = runBlocking {
    val flow = prepareFlow()

    // The first consumer will see both values
    launch {
        flow.collect { println("C1: $it") }
    }

    // Add a second consumer a little later: it sees only the latest state
    delay(10)
    launch {
        flow.collect { println("C2: $it") }
    }
}
```